# Pivot/Crosstab in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-functions

Original data

```
Desc.    Value
-----    ------
Date     01/01/2022
Date     30/04/2021
Date     29/03/2022
Weeksgs  14w 3d
Weeksgs  15w 0d
```

required result

```
Date        Weeksgs
------      --------
01/01/2022  14w 3d
30/04/2021  15w 0d
29/03/2022
```

Comment: If this is in PostgreSQL, as your title suggests, why have you tagged SQL Server?

Comment: even sql solution would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't answer my question; what does SQL Server have to do with the problem? PostgreSQL and SQL Server are completely different products. It's like asking a question about Windows and tagging Ubuntu.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You removed the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76425024/2) @John did.

Comment: i am new to this. sorry for caused inconvenience.

Comment: I don't understand why `14w 3d` would be on the output record for date `01/01/2022`. Can you explain how one arrives at that output?

Comment: this data is available to me.. i want in mentioned format

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to "align" "Date" and "Weeksgs" rows. Assuming that you have a column to order your records, say `id`, you can enumerate the rows in each partition with `row_number()`, then pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select max(val) filter(where descr = 'Date'   ) val_date,
       max(val) filter(where descr = 'Weeksgs') val_weeksgs
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by descr order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by rn
order by rn
```

Note: if "Date" rows *do* represent dates, you might want to convert them to the proper datatype in the resultset; see [`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)